# Edit symlinked files in Dropbox

Tags: symlink

I have a soft symlink between the `Documents` folder on my main computer and a folder in Dropbox, say `dbDocs`. If I now edit a document, say `thesis.tex`, in `dbDocs` from another computer, will the symlink on my main computer see that `thesis.tex` has changed and sync this file back to `Documents`? Or will the symlink just overwrite the newly edited file in `dbDocs` with the corresponding file from `Documents`?

Comment: I'm not sure I got the question. Where is the actual folder and where's the symlink?

Comment: symlinks do not sync - they are a pointer to another file, you need to make the question clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick answer is that if you open `Documents/thesis.tex` after editing it in your `Dropbox` folder on another computer, you **will** see the changes. As @Mark said in a comment, a symlink is simply a pointer to another location on your computer. If that other location has its contents changed, those changes will be visible when using the symlink in `Documents`, just as they would if you examined the file directly in the `Dropbox` folder.

Comment: Ok. So as the files in `Documents` are just pointers to `dbDocs` I'm just confusing myself with thinking about "the file on my main computer". This clarifies.